# How to update links dynamically in StreetView Panorama?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm using the Google Street View to display custom panorama's, and would like a way to dynamically update the links that is displayed in the view (rotating them, adding new ones, and deleting them)

When I say "links" I refer to the arrows you use to navigate inside street view.

Now, I have an array that represents the links I want to add, and when I enter the panorama the first time, they get added properly (through the `links_changed` event), however I have no way to see that the links have updated without jumping back and forth within streetview.

I have tried "tricking" the panorama to think that it has changed with:

```
panorama.setPano(panorama.getPano());
```

I have also tried triggering the `links_changed` event manually by issuing:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(panorama, 'links_changed');
```

which runs the function just fine, but it doesnt do anything within streetview

Here's a JSFiddle that describes my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/p2nZB/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function createCustomLinks() {

    var links = panorama.getLinks();
    var panoId = panorama.getPano();

    links.push({
        heading: parseInt(degInput.value),
        description: 'Something',
        pano: panoId
    });

    panorama.setOptions({
        links: links
    });
}
```

And call `createCustomLinks()` from your click event listener. That should work.

Comment: Ah, never occured to me to use the setOptions method to do it, thank you very much!